# Exporting the calendar monthly view webpart using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar

I am trying to export the webpart and get the xml contains of the webpart in sharepoint online. I am using this link

```
https://intranet.contoso.com/_vti_bin/exportwp.aspx?pageurl=https://intranet.contoso.com/Pages/default.aspx&guidstring=0c3adfe9-8f5d-4432-918a-42410e4e324d
```

This downloads the webpart, but the challenge is to read the value of the downloaded webpart which is xml file, how can i achieve this?

I have also tried using LimitedWebPartManager to export the webpart, `ImportWebPart` and `AddWebPart` is only available, unable to find `ExportWebPart`?